# How can I add a folder to git source control, which i have copied to local git repository, using visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

Is there any way to add a folder to git source control(Like "Add to source control" option for TFVC) from visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the folder has files, and those are included in your project, then you could commit them in the team explorer. (Tab 
 changes)

[image]

Please note that Git doesn't track empty folders. If you need a folder without files, check [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

Update, for files that should not be compiled etc, you could set "build action" to "none" for those files.

[image]

Update 2: if you need those files in Git but not in your project, you need something next to Visual Studio I'm afraid. I could recommend Tortoise Git (https://tortoisegit.org/) for Windows users.

(Or maybe there is a Visual Studio plugin for this)

Comment: Then follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository

Comment: The screenshot attached in your answer is for TFVC source control, right?

Comment: Why can't the files be included in the project then?

Comment: About the screenshot, indeed.  I will update it. Update: fixed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200086/discussion-between-julian-and-rinesh).